# Expand parent div height and the height of the other child div to height of greater child div

Tags: html, css

I have four divs on my asp.net page, div7_1(parent), div4_1 and div11_1 and div6_1 as child divs. This is the situation:

html

```
<div id="div7_1">
   <div id="div4_1">                    
   </div>
   <div id="div11_1" runat="server">                    
   </div>
   <div id="div6_1">
   </div>               
</div>
```

css

```
#div4_1{display:table-cell; width:215px; min-height: 450px; top: 0px; float: left; background-color: #cc9933; text-align: center; border: 2px solid #999;}
#div6_1{display:table-cell; width: 185px; min-height: 450px; float: right; top: 0px; right: 0px; background-color: #cc9933; border: 1px solid #999;}
#div7_1{ position: relative; overflow: hidden; display: table; width: 1200px; min-height: 450px; top: 5px; left: 0px; padding-top: 0px;}
#div11_1{display:table-cell; float: left; padding-left: 5px; margin-left: 5px; width: 65%; min-height: 450px; top: 0px; left: 0px; border: 3px solid #999;}
```

I need to expand parent div height to height of child div with greatest height and expand the other child divs to that height. How can I do this? Probably I have some redundant lines in css, please correct me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you are floating either of the divs but just using `display:table-cell` on **both** seems to achieve your stated requirement

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jwq43/1/)

**CSS**

```
#div7{position: relative; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    display: table; 
    min-height: 450px; 
    top: 5px; 
    left: 0px; 
    padding-top: 0px;}
#div4{display:table-cell; 
    width: 245px; 
    background-color: #cc9933; 
    text-align: center;
    height:150px;
}

#div11{
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;     
    padding-left: 5px; 
    margin-left: 5px; 
    width: 57%; 
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Paulie, I can see on JSfiddle that you are right but on my application it doesn't work. I have the third div in the middle, that is the difference and that's the reason I am floating those two divs. This css is also applied on all of divs but it doesn't work. Middle div expands outer one to his height but left and right divs expand only to height of the corresponding content.

Comment: The display:table for parent and display:table-cell for children did the trick for me. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4z1ua9hz/3/)